# Xpages : Strange behavior of Response Document

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have 2 buttons, button1 (to create response doc for NEW main document) & button2 (to create response doc for existing main doc)
For the first time when I create a new main ‘MyBirthday’ document, and create response, then only 1 response document is created even if I try to create more response documents. This is the time when I hide button1, which saves main document before calling create-responseDoc function.

For second or more entries for response documents, I created button2 which directly calls create-responseDoc function, as my main document is already saved. 
Clicking on button2 doesn’t affect anything. It doesn’t create responses. BUT, if I close and reopen the document.. this same thing works fine.
I am finding it difficult to understand what is actually happening behind the scenes !!

This should be simple but I am stuck somewhere in code or my understanding. 
Here my issue goes: 
I have a main document ‘MyBirthday’. I want to create the response documents ‘MyFamily Birthday’ linked to MyBirthday.  I want this without submitting my Main document(I can save it).

What I did: 
I created Birthday xpage and 2 fields for Family birthday. On click of button ‘Create response doc 1’, first I save the main document using simple actions. Then I create response document via function in SSJS.

I created 2 similar buttons(1st  for new doc, 2nd for existing doc): 1 just above which will save main document first then will call this function & the other button which will not save the main document but will call & create responses.

Function is as below:

```
function fncCreateResponseDoc(currDoc:NotesDocument)
{
    var name = sessionScope.get("FNAME")
    var Bday = sessionScope.get("FBIRTH")
    var respDoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument()
    respDoc.replaceItemValue("Form","rfFamily") 
    respDoc.replaceItemValue("FName",name)
    respDoc.replaceItemValue("FBirthday",Bday)
    respDoc.makeResponse(currDoc)
    respDoc.save()
    respDoc = null
}
```

Then just below, I put a repeat to view these response documents. Data binding formula for repeat goes like this -> `currentDocument.getDocument().getResponses()`

Before saving the main document I set sessionScope variables:

```
sessionScope.put("FNAME",currentDocument.getItemValueString("FName"))
sessionScope.put("FBIRTH",currentDocument.getItemValueDateTime("FBirthday"))
```

Then in postSaveDocument event of this document1:

```
var currDoc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument(true)
fncCreateResponseDoc(currDoc)
```

Please help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ravi, most likely your currDoc doesn't have the docid since it hasn't been saved. Add a currDoc.`save();` to your function in the beginning. also add `respDoc.recyle();` before setting it to null. Furthermore burn a jostick for each `;` you omitted (and don't try to argue about that <vbg>).

let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you Wissel! I could get it. I checked, doc was saved before calling create-response-doc function. I think i was messing around with so many datasources. I repeated the same on new pages and it ran like a charm. Although this time I added ; after every line which I omitted. Thank you.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer :-) In case you wonder about the semicolons, read this: http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons

Comment: Thank you. Interesting blog about semicolons. See you soon :)